# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue. on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Installing json gem failing on ubuntu 14.04
    Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/sumeruadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r./siteconf20150910-31195-1cx4b0u.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/sumeruadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/sumeruadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Please advice
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a valid question so I wonder why it got a -1. I also encountered the same issue, tried to google it and ended up here which helped a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing a libgmp-dev library.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `libcurl3` library, an easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library. It worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```