# Rails Bundle Install Fails at Json Gem: Make Failed

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the following error when trying to do bundle install or even gem install json -v '1.8.1'

```
Installing json 1.8.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160109-4872-1jxs5yc.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_to_s’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                           ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                ^
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/noname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Ruby Version: 2.3.0 and Rails Version: 4.0.3

I tried the solution as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495674/an-error-occurred-while-installing-json-1-8-3-and-bundler-cannot-continue-on), but that didnt work either. 
Please if someone has knowledge of this issue or has fixed this issue in the past could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If the above solution in the link didn't workout for you, please try installing these two

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install libruby2.3
```

let me know if this works

Comment: Hi @kanhaiya-agarwal, thanks for your giving an answer. I installed libgmp3-dev as per your instruction, but for libruby2.3 I got an error :  Unable to locate package libruby2.3. I did sudo apt-get update and then tried again and still had the same error. Do you suppose if I were to use lower version of ruby like 2.2.3 the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Hi @kanhaiya-agarwal, I just followed on what I said, and installed ruby 2.2.3 and everything bundle installed without errors. Well thank you for adding that command: sudo apt-get install libruby2.3 in your answer. Even though it did not work, it peaked my curiosity to check that the culprit was the newest version of ruby.

Comment: yes , as your ruby version was 2.3 i suggested to install other libraries for it Libruby2.3.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, the solution for me were the next commands:

```
rvm get head
rvm –force install 2.3.0 # put your version of ruby
rvm use 2.3.0 # the same version as above
gem install bundle
gem install rails
```